# Large drift (temperature could be a culprit) in this circuit. Anyone can help?

Tags: photodiode, instrumentation-amplifier, transimpedance, drift

**Purpose:** Amplify the differential voltage out of a bi-cell photo-diode. Amplification has to have a high gain as we are looking into nm level displacements of the IR beam centroid emitting the bi-cell

**Circuit:** Below is a schematic of my circuit:

- TA1 and TA2 are the transimpedance amplifiers (LTC6268)
- All the OPs (1-5) are LM324N
- The nulling circuits ensures (\$V_A-V_B\$) is zero in initialization of the circuit.
- \$V_{OS}\$ is the offset voltage that is applied during initialization and will be constant during the operation of our system.
- The 100 k ohms resistors and 3 nF capacitor is to low pass filter the difference between \$V_{AN}\$ and \$V_{BN}\$
- The instrumentation amplifier (INA217) with a variable resistor has gain of 1000
- The output of the instrumentation amplifier is filtered and buffered to get sensOut

I need the high gain in the circuit to be able to pick up the sensOut with my 12 bit DAQ.

**Problem:**
I see large drifts in my circuit, no noise issues though

I appreciate any advice on how to improve my circuit. I am a novice mechatronics student and your feedback is greatly appreciated.

[image: schematic diagram]

A picture of the voltage drift over a 24 hour data recording is below:

[image: sensor output graph showing voltage drift]

Comment: How do you know your Vos is constant?

Comment: I use a 14 bit DAC

Comment: What if you use a mild hair dryer over the circuit?

Comment: What if you turn all lights in the lab?

Comment: Ok - so how do you know that your DAC is constant? What's its reference?

Comment: Shouldn't R8 be 66 kohm?

Comment: It's definitely on a daily cycle. That's clear enough. Temperature certainly may be one part of the problem.

Comment: @Amir Why such high valued resistors in the nulling stage? What's your thinking there?

Comment: @Amir Are you actually feeding your positive voltage rail to the (+) inputs of your transimpedance amplifiers?

Comment: @Amir The leakage in your two photodiodes can readily drift apart from each other with temperature over time. Two opamps also will have slightly different Vos. Themselves also varying slightly with temp. How are you dealing with that?

Comment: How stable are your power supply voltages? And how stable is the VREF of the DAC?

Comment: Are the resisters smd?  The cheap ones tend to suck compared to through-hole.

Comment: There are so many unanswered questions about this that I'm voting to close it as unclear.

Comment: @AliChen: I have tried the hair dryer experiment and I see the drift with it. Environmental temperature could be a reason as the 24H cycle also shows that.

Comment: @AliChen: I have not yet tried the environmental light variation but I could see smaller drifts within half an hour as well. The environmental light variations could be more of a higher frequency fluctuation type rather than a 24H drift cycle right?

Comment: @brhans: I assumed it is within the resolution of the DAC. Do you have any suggestions on how I can improve it and make sure the DAC output is constant?

Comment: @ThePhoton: Why 66k? I even shorted it to the ground with no resistor but did not make much difference in the output

Comment: @jonk: I used the recommended resistors in the LM324 datasheet but is there any specific problem with using large resistors? Do you have any recommended resistor sizes?

Comment: @jonk: I have a separate voltage regulator of +8V to the + input of the trans-impedance terminals and the common of the bi-cell to increase the dynamic range so that I can use higher feedback resistors in the trans-impedance stage.

Comment: @jonk: I have not put anything in the circuit to deal with the issues you mentioned, any suggestions?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf: I used voltage regulators from Digikey. Do you have suggestions on what to incorporate to make it more stable?

Comment: @RobertEndl: They are through hole

Comment: @Amir (I don't think you have the basics right, but I don't have the time right now to worry about it. It could just be me and so I'll assume you designed everything perfectly.) In the best possible cases in my experience, I've been left with difficulties related to the interaction of ambient temperature, variations of offset voltages at the opamps leading to unwanted and unmanaged leakage currents that are also amplified. I've used various techniques to deal with it, but have always had to use them. You are using two photodiodes differentiall, so I think these problems are guaranteed.

Comment: @amir And once I get everything else done (stabilized temperatures via a thermal cooling stack) and/or adjustable offset nulling as well, the problems didn't stop. Once I removed most of the electronic problems, the system became a cosmic ray detector. Seriously. I'd get pulses of 1000 to 10000 electrons showing up on .1 s to 10 s timings. Once I found astronomy papers documenting rates and energies at sea level, it corresponded. So I tried bringing bits of radioactive materials near and sure enough! I could tell the difference between "on edge" and "on face" positions, etc.

Comment: The output from your DAC will only be as stable as the reference you feed into the DAC. This has nothing to do with the DAC's resolution. If the DAC reference drifts by x% then it's output will drift by x% too.

Comment: @Amir, you want the two inputs of the op-amp to "see" the same resistance looking out. Like OP1 has two 100k ohms effectively parallel on the - input, so you put 50 kohms on the + input and all is good. OP2 has three 200k resistors effectively in parallel on the - input, so you want 66 k oh the + input.

Comment: Matching the resistances looking out from the two inputs means that changing bias or input offset currents won't change the output voltage.

Answer (score 1):

I see several problems related to drift.

First of all you have a 10 K trim pot. They have a temperature drift of 200 ppm C. Find out best setting of trim pot and replace most of its value with fixed resistors, 1% or .1%. Get trim pot down to 1 K or 100 ohms if possible, and use Bourns 3396 series 25 turn trim pots.

Second issue is resistor pairs that form a differential circuit, but the resistors counter part should be next to it, else temperature drift is made worse. OP1 and OP2 should be in the same package.

Third. Use low drift resistors, metal film 1% or .1% tolerance if possible. Check with Caddock (Digikey / Mouser) for ultra stable resistors of .025% tolerance if their effect on stability is that important.

Fourth. Dump that POS LM324 and get a real stable op-amp. The LM324 is decades old technology. It also has a poor SNR value. Consider a TL074 series jfet op-amp that will not load down feedback resistors. Look into the OPA series of ultra-stable op-amps as well, though the cost will go up.

NOTE: They are not visible in this schematic, but are your power supplies very stable? Is your ADC Vref ultra stable? At 12 bits tiny drifts and errors begin to show. If your having bit-locking distortion in the ADC inject pink noise equal to 1/2 LSB of the ADC Vref.

Comment: Thanks @Sparky256 for the answer. I would incorporate your suggestions and report back here.